# CMOS frequency of oscillation

Tags: astable, multivibrator

How to find the frequency of oscillations in this circuit CMOS circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOoYjP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming the ideal CMOS gate with the threshold at 0.5Vdd.

And the output and the input waveform if an inverter.

[image]

R = 10kΩ; C = 1nF; IC = CD4069; Vdd = 5V

How would you approach it?

Comment: I'd use a simulator because trying to work through a hundred iterations of cap charge and discharge until the maxima and minima have settled is too laborious.

Comment: I know what you meant @Andyaka. Without knowing the "past" it seems impossible to solve. But maybe there is a way?

Comment: It's also possible if they were matched in same IC and you reset the supply, that it could oscillate at 50MHz or where the slew rate of the Inverter = RC all all outputs are linear at the same time with triangle inputs.

Comment: Actually, figuring the max and min is tedious, but not nearly as much as @Andyaka would have you believe. Assuming that the inverters have equal strength in pullup and pulldown, the fact that the max and min must be symmetrical around Vdd/2 simplifies the issue considerably. Still not fun, but not impossible.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I wouldn't have anyone believe it is too tedious - it's all down to how much accuracy you want and by the time you have got some form of an answer, the guy using a sim would be an hour ahead.

Comment: @Andyaka - Oh sure, the sim is the way to go. But my point is that "trying to work through a hundred iterations" is not necessary. Granted, that's what the sim does, but people are (or can be) smarter than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just throw this in here. Given **ideal** inverters, ie. they work like ideal comparators, with infinite gain and low output impedance. Note that this is not the case judging from your simulated waveforms.

You can observe the following:

1. The RC-filter will generate a waveform that is symmetrical over \$V_{DD}/2\$ in steady-state. If we call the minimum value \$V_m\$, then the maximum value is \$V_{DD}-V_m\$
2. When applying an **ideal** square wave to an RC-filter, the exponential will follow the equation (t=0 at the start of the period):

$$v_{out}(t) = V_m + (V_{DD}-V_m) \left(1 - e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\right)$$

3. Calling the period \$T\$, then the waveform will reach it's maximum value \$V_{DD}-V_m\$ at \$t=T/2\$, or

$$V_m + (V_{DD}-V_m)\left(1 - e^{-\frac{T/2}{RC}}\right) = V_{DD} - V_m \\
$$

4. Also, since the input switches after the output has passed through all 3 stages, the exponential should reach \$V_{DD}/2\$ at \$t=T/6\$.

$$V_m + (V_{DD}-V_m)\left(1 - e^{-\frac{T/6}{RC}}\right) = \frac{V_{DD}}{2}$$

You can solve these equations to finally get

$$T = -6RC \ln\left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$

Plugging in your values would result in

$$T = -6\cdot 10k\Omega\cdot 1nF\cdot \ln\left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \approx 28.9\mu s$$

(this is around 35kHz)

From your measurements, it looks like your inverters are switching slower, so a longer period is to be expected. I guess this formula will in any case indicate a maximum frequency.

---

**Appendix**

Steps for working out the formula:

From point 3:
$$\left(1 - e^{-\frac{T/2}{RC}}\right) = \frac{V_{DD} - 2V_m}{V_{DD} - V_m}$$

From point 4:
$$2\left(1 - e^{-\frac{T/6}{RC}}\right) = \frac{V_{DD} - 2V_m}{V_{DD} - V_m}$$

This allows us to eliminate \$V_m\$:

$$\begin{align}
1 - e^{-\frac{T/2}{RC}} &= 2\left(1 - e^{-\frac{T/6}{RC}}\right) \\
&\Downarrow (y = e^{-\frac{T}{6RC}}) \\
1 - y^3 &= 2(1 - y) \\
&\Downarrow \\
y^2 + y - 1 &= 0 \\
&\Downarrow (y > 0) \\
y = e^{-\frac{T}{6RC}} &= \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \\
&\Downarrow \\
T &= -6RC\cdot \ln\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: This not a simulation result I posted a scope capture from a bench prototype that I made.

Comment: The simulation shows for almost the ideal case F around 33.4kHz

Comment: How did you manage to get rid of a Vm from the equation?

Comment: I edited the answer to include the steps to get there.

Answer (score 7):

Because the delay around the loop must be 360 degrees (why? Because the output at the junction of R3/C3 is identical to the input of the first inverter), it's clear that the phase shift of each section must be 120 degrees. And since this represents the sum of the RC phase shift plus the 180 degree phase shift supplied by the inverter, the RC phase shift must be 60 degrees.

Since phase shift angle is
$$\phi = \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2\pi fRC }  $$
set the angle to \$\pi/3\$ and solve.

EDIT -

Please note that this approach only works for phase shift oscillators with a small number of stages. If you have a lot of stages, each RC spends most of its time at one level or the other, and the concept of phase really won't apply well. In this particular case, you can see that the RC waveform is not too far off from a sinusoid, so the linear criteria work pretty well. They'll work even better, of course for a sinusoid, but beggars can't be choosers.

END EDIT

Comment: Interesting approach \$ F = \frac{1.73}{2 \pi RC} = 27.5 \textrm{kHz} \$ Not bad.

Comment: I think, this is the only possible approach. As for each oscillator, it is the Barkhausen criterion which gives the solution - nothing else.

Comment: Using your brain gets +1 from me.

Comment: @G36 - With all due modesty, yeah. That and luck, of course. Especially since caps are usually (at best) 10% tolerance, and often 20%, and the observed frequency is good to 2%. So let's hear it for luck.

Comment: @LvW Even for the "relaxation oscillator" Barkhausen criterion can predict the frequency of operation?

Comment: @G36 - See edit.

Comment: This formula is valid and accurate for small-signal linear mode. This circuit doesn't have automatic gain control to get into linear mode (aka "sinusoid"), so there must some frequency shift/correction due to nonlinearity of the signal.

Comment: Ali Chen, yes - "some" frequency shift. But this is true - in principle - for each and every oscillator. All working oscillators have a certain non-linearity. However, the question is: Does it matter? Remember: Even the principle of "harmonic balance" (first harmonic analysis) - applied to strongly non-linear oscillators - is based on the Barkhausen criterion - which very good success.

Comment: G36, sorry - only now I have recognized that your last comment was a question. The shown oscillator is NOT a relaxation oscillator. It is a "normal" feedback oscillator (with a positive loop gain) - however, with excessive loop gain driving the active blocks into saturation. But the same effect can be observed, for example, when the classical WIEN-type oscillator is operated with a gain of 4 or 5 (instead of 3.1).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say each stage has a time constant of about RC = 10us so total timeconstant is 30 us for 3 stages, 1/30 us = 33 kHz

You measure 28 kHz so for me my calculation above is close enough for a "ballpark" figure, 1st order approximation, whatever you like to call it.

My calculation ignores any additional effects caused by the inverters. I expect these effects to delay the signal even more causing the frequency to be lower, which it is.

If you want a more accurate number then it gets complex as the output resistance of the inverters (which is varying with the signal amplitude) comes into play. Then using a simulator is needed, note that you would then also need a proper model of the actual inverters you're using.

Comment: Well, I never thought about is this way. Because for a single gate and RC circuit the delay is 0.7RC. So, for 3 stages 2.1RC which is not true.

Comment: @G36 Instead of delay maybe "time constant" is a better word, so I replaced "delay" with "time constant"

Answer (score 1):

If the inverters are ideal, then the oscillation speed is infinite in the limit and the RC stages are transparent. So the RC stages cannot be analyzed without the inverters being non-ideal. Try to prove this to yourself first. That should tell you something about what’s important in this circuit.

Up to a point its performance is determined mostly by the gates, and only when the gates act like linear amplifiers with finite gain does the behavior depend on RC stages. CD4000 family is rather docile so in this particular circuit the non-ideality of the gates makes it tractable.

A hint as to why too good gates would mess things up: such gates are very much non-linear. Linear models don’t do a good job describing them.

So, for the circuit here, working from say 12V a decent model may be each gate replaced with an ideal inverting amplifier with gain of say 100, with reference voltage at half supply. Now you should have plenty of references to tackle it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simulation showing oscillation at 33 kHz. The time constant of each RC network is 10 uSec, so three TCs provide the expected frequency.

Note that I had to change R4 and R6 to make it oscillate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqqAj6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]